# Why are some non-OEM updates only available from the OEM update software?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update, oem

Why are some non-OEM updates only available from the OEM update software?

I have a Dell computer, I just did a Windows update check, and it says "You're up to date", but then a check with "Dell Update" application shows an update for "Realtek High Definition Audio Driver".

I thought all driver providers publish updates to Windows update before anywhere else?

What's going on?

Comment: Please provide more info, such as your PC model, audio card/integrated audio type, driver version, etc., as your question as written is not possible to answer

Comment: Microsoft offers drivers that are compatible with windows in general, but not the latest driver that Dell has to offer, Windows updates only knows it is Windows and not that its a Dell. Oems customize their drivers and Microsoft has no way to offer that one only to Dell computers.

Comment: The shift from OEM to Microsoft is a work-in-progress. Sometimes Microsoft is up-to-date and sometimes it is not. You need to check Dell Updates (or HIP Updates or Lenovo Updates) after you run Windows Updates.